# SQL join statement with where clause

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have this question, from I am trying to get through. I have been trying to do this for hours, it would be really great if someone could point us in the right direction.

This is in german so I am going to translate it in English:

We only have problem with part (d)

(d) Write an SQL statement that gives names of the restaurant and Ort(Place) of the restaurant that do not order any Salat.

The expected result would be:

Da Mafia : Göttingen
Venezia  : Kassel

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
  SELECT name,ort FROM kunde WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(pizzeria) FROM Liefervertrag WHERE product='salat')
```

Comment: Yes it did help and I am going to accept it, I just have another question: can this also be done with some fancy join statement? I mean you solution is correct, but I was just wondering

Comment: Yeah, you can do it by using JOIN but that will be irrelevant in this scenario......You can just join kunde  and Liefervertrag  with checking the condtion in product......

Comment: Try with using this query for JOIN : SELECT a.name,a.ort FROM konde a JOIN Liefervertrag b ON a.name = b.pizzeria WHERE b.prodokt NOT IN ('salad')

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't apply to LolCoder's answer, but remember to be careful with NOT IN when the subquery has nulls.

This is another approach with variations on the theme. It's not exactly fancy even though it does use an inner join. You'll probably find them all in the wild.

My preference is the first one. I'm also usually explicit about "else null" even though isn't technically necessary.

```
-- A
SELECT name, min(ort) as ort
FROM kunde as k INNER JOIN Liefervertrag as l on l.pizzeria = k.name
GROUP by name
HAVING count(case when l.product = 'salat' then 1 else null end) = 0

-- B
SELECT name, min(ort) as ort
FROM kunde as k INNER JOIN Liefervertrag as l on l.pizzeria = k.name
GROUP by name
HAVING sum(case when l.product = 'salat' then 1 else 0 end) = 0

-- C
SELECT name, ort
FROM kunde as k INNER JOIN Liefervertrag as l on l.pizzeria = k.name
GROUP by name, ort
HAVING count(case when l.product = 'salat' then 1 else null end) = 0

-- D
SELECT name, ort
FROM kunde as k INNER JOIN Liefervertrag as l on l.pizzeria = k.name
GROUP by name, ort
HAVING sum(case when l.product = 'salat' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: But I do not seem to get this to work. I keep on getting an error: "k.product not found in Having clause" I have checked all the spellings and typos...

Comment: I found out why... there is a slight typo in here... "k.product" in having clause should be "l.product" but otherwise it is working just fine!

Comment: I (with all due respect and gratefulness :P) have edited your answer

Comment: Thanks. Since I don't know German I did a little more flipping back an forth, but it was still my own silly mistake.