# Database Query + relational algebra

Tags: mysql

I have this question, from I am trying to get through. I have been trying to do this for hours, it would be really great if someone could point us in the right direction.

```
Customer(name, city, address)                //name is a primary key
ContractToDelivery(pizzeria, product, count) // [pizzeria and product] is a primary key
Pricelist(product, price)                    //product is a primary key
```

You can see on this site the tables [SQL join statement with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377425/sql-join-statement-with-where-clause).

I have problems with this part:

Write an SQL statement that gives names of restaurants(customer) who get delivered all the
offered products . (same in relational algebra)

Products are pizza, lasagne, Gnocchi an salad.

Comment: When you say 'a key' presumably you mean a PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585969/join-with-multiple-table

Comment: this don't answer my question..

Comment: @blue What have you tried? Where are you get stuck? By the way: the resultset should be empty :-) Can't you see there's no difference between "Give me the students that have classes by all professors" and "Give me the restaurands that get delivered all offered products"?